# Nested noweb in org src blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, noweb

I have the following code blocks:

Block 1 is just one line. This is a MWE. In reality, I have several lines in block 1.

```
#+name: block1
#+begin_src python :noweb no :exports none
print("Block 1")
#+end_src
```

Block 2 has also been reduced for the sake of MWE.

```
#+name: block2
#+begin_src python :noweb no :exports none
<<block1>>
print("Block 2")
#+end_src
```

This shows a skeleton of myfunc. I want to include this skeleton to give an overview of myfunc.

```
#+name: block3
#+begin_src python :noweb no :exports code
def myfunc(x):
    <<block2>>
#+end_src
```

Finally, this shows the full specification of myfunc.

```
#+begin_src python :noweb yes :exports code
<<block3>>
#+end_src
```

**What I expect it to look like when exported**

```
def myfunc(x):
    print("Block 1")
    print("Block 2")
```

**What it actually looks like**

```
def myfunc(x):
    <<block1>>
    print("Block 2")
```

How can I get the nested blocks to expand completely when I use :noweb yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works if I set all headers with `:noweb yes` and then only the last block has `:tangle yes`.

A simpler example:

1. Add this at the top of the file: `#+PROPERTY: header-args :noweb yes :tangle no :exports code`
2. Remove all header args from the code blocks.
3. Add `:tangle yes` header to the "full specification".

Comment: Thanks. I could make this work with a slight change to get whet I wanted -- I set all the headers to `:noweb no-export`. That way the blocks are not expanded in my exported pdf, but are expanded in the tangled code. (I realize now that my question did not clarify this well enough).